# Update Header View of listView on image download complete

Tags: android, android-listview

I am working on an app that is fetching data from server, I have a list View containing a header view i am downloading an image and on its completion I want to update my header view, how can i achieve this ?

I am also updating my items and they are updating successfully but I don't know how to get my header View in the adapter and update it ...

Comment: Please post your code what you have done so far...

Answer (score 1):

Hold reference to the text view used in the list view header.

I assume you add list view header like below:

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);    
TextView headerText = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
headerText.setText("This is my header!");
myListView.addHeaderView(header);
```

once the image download completes, you can notify using some interface/listeners and then update the text view.

Answer (score 1):

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
    }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
   }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);
   }
}
```

I hope this may help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I just got a solution and i am posting here so it can be useful for every one

I just simply send the reference of the headerView in the constructor of the list adapter and download image there and set the image there to its zero index item that is header view

```
public class MainListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataObjects>{

    private int layoutResourceID;
    private ArrayList<DataObjects> dataObjects;
    private Context context;
    private ListHolder listHolder;
    private View headerView;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Boolean flagBitmap = false;

    public MainListViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID, ArrayList<DataObjects> objects, View headerView) {
        super(context, layoutResourceID, objects);
        this.layoutResourceID = layoutResourceID;
        this.dataObjects = objects;
        this.context = context;
        this.headerView = headerView;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            new DownloadImageTask(this.dataObjects.get(0).getImageURL()).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[])null);
        else
            new DownloadImageTask(this.dataObjects.get(0).getImageURL()).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        listHolder = new ListHolder();
        if(row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceID, parent, false);

            row.setTag(listHolder);

        } else {
            listHolder = (ListHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        DataObjects list = dataObjects.get(position);

        if(position == 0) {
            ImageView imageViewHeader = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHeaderImage);

            if(flagBitmap)
                imageViewHeader.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                imageViewHeader.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample);
        }


        return row;
    }

    private class ListHolder {
        TextView textViewDate;
        ImageView imageViewMagazine;
        Button buttonPreview, buttonDownload;
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

        private String URL;

        public DownloadImageTask(String URL) {
            this.URL = URL;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(URL).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if(result != null) {
                setThumbBitmap(result);
                setThumbAvailable(true);
            }
        }

        public void setThumbBitmap(Bitmap thumbBitmap) {
            bitmap = thumbBitmap;
        }

        public void setThumbAvailable(boolean thumbAvailable) {
            flagBitmap = thumbAvailable;
        }
    }
}
```